# Interpretation of estimates for a model with 2 categorial factors

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, model, gamlss

I ran a model with 2 fixed factors that are categorial:

```
Ind: 10 levels
CRENEAU: 4 levels
```

For the parameter `nu` (I am running a `gamlss` of family `BEZI`), I get this summary:

```
Nu link function:  logit   
Nu Coefficients:
                 Estimate  
(Intercept)     2.180e+00  
IndF2           9.259e-01     
IndF3           9.259e-01      
IndF4          -4.184e-01     
IndF5           4.126e-15      
IndT1          -6.434e-01   
IndT2           9.259e-01      
IndT3          -1.623e+00  
IndT4           3.763e-01     
IndT5          -1.412e+00  
CRENEAUEVENING -3.071e-01    
CRENEAUMORNING  2.379e-01   
CRENEAUNOON     5.507e-01
```

`CRENEAU` and `Ind` are 2 different factors linked to my response. I understand that the intercept is the level of `IndF1`. But what is the estimate for the missing level of `CRENEAU`? Is there only one intercept for both factors that is equal ?

Comment: Yes, the intercept is the value for *all* of your reference levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to write out the equation, the intercept is the log odds of your outcome variable (`Y`) when all predictors included in the model are set to zero.

So it is the log odds of `Y` when none of the nine included `IND` categories apply and none of the three included `CRENEAU` categories apply.

Hence, it is the log-odds for individuals in the base category for both categories! So for those in `INDF1` and `CRENEAUNIGHT` (this is me guessing the base categories).

Comment: Ok thanks. The calculation for the estimate of InfF2 for exemple is inverse logit (estimate IndF2) or inverse logit( intercept + estimate IndF2) ?

Comment: The marginal effect on the log odds of InfF2 is the estimate for IndF2. Because you have another categorical variable, you can't really look at the overall estimate for IndF2 without considering the other variable. For example, the overall log odds for IndF2 and CRENEAUNIGHT (base) is (intercept + estimate IndF2). Likewise, the log odds for IndF2 and CRENEAUEVENING is (intercept + estimate IndF2 + estimate CRENEAUEVENING).